# Past simple vs. present perfect (concrete example)

Tags: present-perfect

My son just had this example in a test and had to fill in the blanks:

> He _____ (not meet) a famous person in his life, _____?

He answered:

> He didn't meet a famous person in his life, did he?

But the correct answer would have been:

> He has not met a famous person in his life, has he?

And, fair enough, I fully understand that they wanted the second version. Just out of curiosity: Is the first one just wrong under any circumstances or does it imply something more specific, namely that "his" life is already over and during all of it never met a famous person. While in the first one, "he" is probably still alive but hasn't met famous person so far?

Comment: It's a stupid test. Who's to say the context *(which we **don't** have)* wouldn't be better served by ***Past** Perfect* - *He **hadn't** met a famous person in his life, **had** he?*

Comment: It's a very poorly written question for a test because without a context, just about any tense could fit there. Consider, "*He **wouldn't have had to** meet a famous person in his life, **would he**?*", which is also correct. You correctly understand the difference in meaning.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Did not*" (or '*didn't*') is the negative version of the simple past tense.

"*Has not*" (or '*hasn't*) is the present perfect.

So, as you said - 'did not' limits the scope to the past, rather than the past *up to and including the present*, so it does make it sound like you're speaking about a person who is no longer alive.

Of course, it wouldn't always mean the person was dead - if the context is referring to a period of time that has ended, for example, "*while on vacation, I did not go in the pool*".

Comment: Thank you for the reply!